# SVM Classifications on set of images of digits in Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, digits

I have to use SVM classifier on digits dataset. The dataset consists of images of digits 28x28 and a toal of 2000 images.
I tried to use svmtrain but the matlab gave an error that svmtrain has been removed. so now i am using fitcsvm.

My code is as below:

```
labelData = zeros(2000,1);

for i=1:1000
labelData(i,1)=1;
end

for j=1001:2000
labelData(j,1)=1;
end

SVMStruct =fitcsvm(trainingData,labelData) 
%where training data is the set of images of digits.
```

I need to know how i can predict the outputs of test data using svm? Further is my code correct?

Answer (score 1):

The function that you are looking for is [`predict`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classreg.learning.classif.compactclassificationsvm.predict.html;jsessionid=488561cb6962b63006df8856d93d). It takes the SVM-object as input followed by a data-matrix and returns the predicted labels.
Make sure that you do not train your model on all data but on a reasonable subset (usually 70%). You can use the [cross-validation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html#d117e255870) preparation:

```
% create cross-validation object
cvp = cvpartition(Lbl,'HoldOut',0.3);
% extract logical vectors for training and testing data
lgTrn = cvp.training;
lgTst = cvp.test;

% train SVM
mdl = fitcsvm(Dat(lgTrn,:),Lbl(lgTrn));

% test / predict SVM
Lbl_prd = predict(mdl,Dat(lgTst,:));
```

Note that your labeling produces a single vector of ones.

The reason why The Mathworks changed `svmtrain` to `fitcsvm` is conciseness. It is now clear whether it is "classification" (fit**c**svm) or "regression" (fit**r**svm).